# Windows Development with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning flutter right now and want to know which platforms support flutter applications.
I know that flutter supports iOS and Android.
I want to know if we can run flutter programs on windows.

Comment: Kindly refer to the project info page https://flutter.dev/

Answer (score 0):

Flutter Desktop:

> currently this effort is still under way

Google has an example project [project](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding).

About Flutter on Windows:

> The current Windows shell is a GLFW placeholder, to allow early
>   experimentation. It will be replaced in the future with a Win32 or UWP
>   shell that allows view-level embedding of Flutter within an
>   application.
>
> Expect the APIs for the final shell to be radically different from the
>   current implementation.

Source: [Wiki](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Desktop-shells)